# Copying data based on the headers from Sheet1 to Sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge Excel sheet with about 2000 rows.

- So Row 1 is the first header, the columns are: Unique Name, Length, Elevation. Then there is a bunch of data related to these columns.
- Row 8 is another header, the columns are: Unique Name, Elevation, Element type. Again some data follows these columns.
- And so on goes the Excel sheet with many such rows which are headers.

These headers are not in same order. Here is an example of Excel Sheet1:

```
    Unique Name     Length (ft)   Elevation (ft)              this is Row 1 (header1)
      A              20             4                         this is Row 2
      B               5             10                        this is Row 3
      C              10             3
      D              11             40
      E               3             60
                                                              Row 7 is blank
    Unique Name     Elevation (ft)  Element Type              this is Row 8 (header2)
      1              20              Pipe
      2               5              Pipe
      3              10              Pipe
                                                              Row 12 is blank
    Unique Name     Element Type    Elevation     Status      this is Row 13 (header 3)         
      A1              VALVE           10           Open
      A2              VALVE            2           Open
      A3              VALVE           100          Open
      .                .               .            .
      .                .               .            .
      .                .               .            .
      .                .               .            .
```

I need to copy every single columns data from Sheet1 based on specific headers and paste it to Sheet2.

Here is an example of Sheet2, this is what I need:

```
  Unique Name     Length (ft)   Elevation (ft)   Status    Element Type             this is the only header I need
      A              20             4                        
      B               5             10                        
      C              10             3
      D              11             40
      E               3             60
      1                             20                         Pipe
      2                             5                          Pipe
      3                             10                         Pipe       
      A1                            10            Open         VALVE  
      A2                            2             Open         VALVE 
      A3                            100           Open         VALVE 
      .                .               .            .           .
      .                .               .            .           .
      .                .               .            .           .
      .                .               .            .           .
```

I have searched a lot, and Alex's VBA code below is the closest I found in this help forum. But it obviously works only for data belonging to Row 1 Header.

```
Sub CopyPasteData()
Dim header As Range, headers As Range
Set headers = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1")
For Each header In headers
If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))                                          
End If
Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
Dim headers As Range
Set headers = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:Z1")
GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)),      
Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just filter to the header rows and delete all but the first one

Comment: Hey Doug, I can't do that since every header is different, for example Row 1 header is Unique Name, Length, Elevation. Row 10 header will be Unique Name, Element Type, Elevation, Status. So if I filter and delete all row headers except first one, the whole data will mess up.

Comment: @raji, Is the problem finding the next header row or getting the data from there into Sheet2?  If finding the header row is the problem, what is the structure around them (a blank row above or just a wall of text)?  It looks like you have good code to copy to the right place.  A screenshot might help for the first issue as well.  You can blur the data or black it out since it likely doesn't affect the solution.

Comment: I see. An picture/example of the data would be good.

Comment: @ByronWall, the problem is both of them. There are actually blank rows above each new header. So the above code copies and paste data belonging to header1 only and then it doesn't go further because it doesn't have iterations built into it. Just need to figure out how to change it so that it works for the whole sheet.

Comment: Is "Unique Name" always present in column A of the header rows?

Comment: @Comintern, yes that is the only consistent part in Sheet1. "Unique Name" is always present in Column A for every single header rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be easy enough to do if you can key off of the "Unique Name" in the first column as an indicator that a new header has been reached.  You basically just need to keep track of 3 different mappings - columns for headings that have already been located, rows for unique names that have already been located, and the positions of the headers in the current section.

Dictionaries from the Microsoft Scripting Runtime work well for this.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
Private Sub MergeSections()

    Dim source As Worksheet, target As Worksheet
    Dim found As Dictionary, current As Dictionary, uniques As Dictionary

    Set source = ActiveSheet
    Set target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set found = New Dictionary
    Set uniques = New Dictionary

    Dim row As Long, col As Long, targetRow As Long, targetCol As Long
    targetRow = 2
    targetCol = 2

    Dim activeVal As Variant
    For row = 1 To source.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        'Is the row a header row?
        If source.Cells(row, 1).Value2 = "Unique Name" Then
            'Reset the current column mapping.
            Set current = New Dictionary
            For col = 2 To source.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                activeVal = source.Cells(row, col).Value2
                If activeVal <> vbNullString Then
                    current.Add col, activeVal
                    'Do you already have a column mapped for it?
                    If Not found.Exists(activeVal) Then
                        found.Add activeVal, targetCol
                        targetCol = targetCol + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next col
        Else
            activeVal = source.Cells(row, 1).Value2
            'New unique name?
            If Not uniques.Exists(activeVal) Then
                'Assign a row in the target sheet.
                uniques.Add activeVal, targetRow
                target.Cells(targetRow, 1).Value2 = activeVal
                targetRow = targetRow + 1
            End If
            For col = 2 To source.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                'Copy values.
                activeVal = source.Cells(row, col).Value2
                If source.Cells(row, col).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
                    target.Cells(uniques(source.Cells(row, 1).Value2), _
                                 found(current(col))).Value2 = activeVal
                End If
            Next col
        End If
    Next row

    'Write headers to the target sheet.
    target.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = "Unique Name"
    For Each activeVal In found.Keys
        target.Cells(1, found(activeVal)).Value2 = activeVal
    Next activeVal

End Sub
```